# How to implement fire detector (smoke+temperature) for an electronics project?

Tags: sensor

I am doing a project of which fire detection (smoke detection) is a part. I want to detect smoke and then trigger a alarm via a micro controller (preferably MSP430 or PIC)
I am looking for basic circuits that can do the needful.
Any help would be appreciated.
I have found TGS308/813 ICs to be useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to detect smoke.

The simplest for your project would be a dedicated smoke sensor such as the MQ2. It is basically designed to be interfaced to uCs with 5V inputs. Read the wiki for more examples.

[image]

(http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/grove-gas-sensormq2-p-937.html)

If this is not a good example consider using an IR photodiode with trans-impedance amplifier to detect fire. You can also just buy a home fire/smoke detection, take off the cover and wire it's outputs into your uC (probably through some level shifting circuitry.